# Wordpress REST API: Line break in json post_content

Tags: wordpress, api

I am creating some custom routes in the wordpress API. Everything works fine, but I'm having a problem retrieving the post_content of a post. The format in json is not valid. Make a line break.

[image]

[image]

If you remove all html tags with wp_strip_all_tags it works fine, but it is not the case to use it. I want to keep the labels.

```
 'descripcion' => get_post_field('post_content', $post->ID)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried like this?

```
html_entity_decode(get_post_field('post_content', $post->ID), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

or

```
htmlentities(get_post_field('post_content', $post->ID), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

Please read the PHP documentation of this 2 functions.